# Swift 4: UISearchBar and NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to add a `UISearchBar` programatically in `UINavigationBar`.

In my storyboard I drag and drop the a `UINavigationBar` and `UITableView`.

The problem is, when I run the application and pull down the `tableview`, the `SearchBar` is not showing.

here is my code,

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

// MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

// Setup the Search Controller
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search "
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
definesPresentationContext = true


searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

**The only way to make it work is to embedded the navigation controller.**
How can I make it work without the navigation controller?

I update my poste with the suggestion below and as you can see the searchbar can't hide when scrolling and  even the "HI" label and the button are disappearing

[image]

```
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    let item = UINavigationItem.init()
    item.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    item.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    self.NavigationBAr.setItems([item], animated: true)
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: try this self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController

Comment: you want searchResultsController or just seachbar ?

Comment: @DevilDecoder this will keep the searchbar visible and nod hiding all the time while scrolling

Comment: @HardikThakkar just a searchbar

Comment: I think it’s not possible without a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @Mannopson i don't understand why i have to use a UINavigationControlle cz this will cause me another issue since my viewcontroller will not be showen modaly /full screen on Ipad. i am using Master details with split view

Comment: you write code for searchController, please change that first

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        let item = UINavigationItem.init()
        item.titleView = searchController
        self.navigationbar.setItems([item], animated: true)
```

Comment: I will try it, I don' t know if this way the searchbar will hide when scrolling down

Comment: I update my post with screen shot and as you can see the search bar won't hiding when scrolling and the label/button in the navbar are disappeared